# Direction selector used on last menus, item causing ? to be set at the front of box text

Tags: jquery, css

I use the "direction" selector on my last 2 menu items so that the drop down menu doesn't spill off the page at lower resolutions. This has worked great, until a question mark was added to the menu name. Causing "How To" to be "?How To"

I sorted this by adding ltr on the "a" tag child elements 
(So now all my other menu items flow left to right, with the last two being right to left)

Is there a better way to set the last menu item to be right to left, which doesn't reverse the text should any characters such as ? be added.

```css
#menu > ul > li:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
    direction: rtl;
}


#menu > ul > li > a:nth-last-of-type(-n+2) {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="mycategory.php">How To?</a>
  <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="mysubcatlink.php">Getting Started</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: If you want to apply css to last item, use `:last-of-type` or `:last-child`